# db2 create stored procedure to increment number

Tags: java, jpa, db2

I need create a new stored to increment a number, but I need what the table is locked before.

I coded this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_NEXT_OPERATION_NUMBER (
        IN TYPE INTEGER,
        OUT OPERATION_NUMBER INTEGER
)
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1 
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *CS , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX 
P1: BEGIN

    LOCK TABLE SMPORDD.R08FNTR IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

    SET OPERATION_NUMBER = (SELECT R08NRO FROM SMPORDD.R08FNTR where R08IDT = TYPE);
 
    SET OPERATION_NUMBER = OPERATION_NUMBER + 1;
   
    UPDATE SMPORDD.R08FNTR SET R08NRO = OPERATION_NUMBER  WHERE R08IDT = TYPE; 
 
    COMMIT;
END P1
```

Someone can validate that?

I get this error when I execute in java jpa.

`11:47:50,828 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-11) SQL Error: -913, SQLState: 57033 11:47:50,831 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-11) [SQL0913] Fila u objeto R08FNTR en SMPORDD tipo *FILE utilizándose.`

Comment: Check out Db2 Sequences - they will generate the numbers for you and will not create such a "hot spot" causing locking problems.

Comment: Do you have a relatively static number of types?

Answer (score 0):

You are locking the table, you should be doing a transaction.

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
    SET OPERATION_NUMBER = (SELECT R08NRO + 1 FROM SMPORDD.R08FNTR where R08IDT = TYPE);
    UPDATE SMPORDD.R08FNTR SET R08NRO = OPERATION_NUMBER  WHERE R08IDT = TYPE; 
    COMMIT;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLCODE = [-913](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n913.html) is deadlock or timeout.
The concurrency issue.

> **Explanation**
> The application was the victim in a deadlock or
> experienced a timeout. The reason code indicates whether a deadlock or
> timeout occurred.
>
> ***reason-code***
> The Db2 reason code value that indicates the reason for
> the failure. For explanations of reason codes, see Db2 reason codes.
>
> ***resource-type and resource-name***
> The type and name of the resource that
> the message identifies. For an explanation of resource-type and
> resource-name values, see Resource types.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, using one or more sequence(s) will cause less lock contention. In addition, I'm not 100% sure that your semaphore will work unless you use serializable isolation level (I think snapshot isolation level will also guarantee that, but it is not implemented in Db2).

If you don't mind gaps and that types get mixed from the same sequence, one sequence is the easiest possible scenario:

```
SELECT R08NRO AS OPERATION_NUMBER
FROM FINAL TABLE (
    UPDATE SMPORDD.R08FNTR 
        SET R08NRO = NEXT VAL FOR <THE_SEQUENCE>
    WHERE R08IDT = TYPE
);
```

If needed, you can create one sequence per type and use dynamic sql to construct the name of the sequence (still wont prevent gaps though, a sequence number is consumed when it is pulled from the sequence, say in case of rollback)

What you are trying to do was a popular pattern in the beginning of the Java EE era. I get the impression that it was massively abandoned due to the problems it caused.